# ¿Cómo puedo mover o colocar en otra área los botones para exportar de DataTable?

Tags: php, datatables, vue3, laravel-10, inertia.js

Estoy realizando un proyecto en Laravel con Inertia y vue, y estoy usando DataTables para mostrar datos y los botones que trae como extensión para exportar los datos como PDF, Excel, Imprimir y copiar. Estoy intentando mover esos botones a un div diferente o a otra área sin embargo no lo he logrado. He intentado usar la propiedad container pero al parecer no funciona:

```
const botones2 = [
{
    title: 'Alumnos registrados',
    extend: 'excelHtml5',
    text: '<i class="fa-solid fa-file-excel"></i> Excel',
    className: 'bg-cyan-500 hover:bg-cyan-600 text-white py-1/2 px-3 rounded mb-2',
    exportOptions: {
        columns: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
    },
    container: '#excel'
},
```

De igual forma intente colocarlo dentro de la configuración al crear el DataTable:

```
<DataTable class="w-full table-auto text-sm display nowrap stripe compact cell-border order-column"
            id="alumnosTablaId" name="alumnosTablaId" :columns="columns2" :data="alumnos" :options="{
                responsive: true, autoWidth: false, dom: 'Bftrip', language: {
                    search: 'Buscar', zeroRecords: 'No hay registros para mostrar',
                    info: 'Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros',
                    infoEmpty: 'Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros',
                    infoFiltered: '(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)',
                    lengthMenu: 'Mostrar _MENU_ registros',
                    paginate: { first: 'Primero', previous: 'Anterior', next: 'Siguiente', last: 'Ultimo' },
                }, buttons: [{container: '#excel'},{botones2}], 
            }">
            <thead>
```

De igual forma intente hacerlo con lo siguiente:

```
 initComplete: function () {
    // Asegúrate de que "this" se refiera a la instancia de la tabla DataTable
    const table = this.api();

    // Mover los botones al contenedor deseado
    const btnContainer = document.querySelector('.excel');

    if (btnContainer && table) {
        table.buttons().container().appendTo(btnContainer);
    }
},
```

Sin embargo, no he podido realizarlo de ninguna forma.
He intentado tanto en un div como en un button, los cuales han llevado el id y el class excel

Comment: que dice la documentación???